# use call_user_func in PHP 8 returns fatal error

Tags: php, php-8

I am trying to call a class named *ContactController* with the function *handleContact* with `call_user_func([ContactController::class, 'handleContact']);` but got following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method app\controllers\ContactController::handleContact() cannot be called statically

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

class ContactController {
    public function handleContact() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the method handleContact is static than call it:

```
call_user_func([ContactController::class, 'handleContact'])
```

If your method handleContact is not static than you need to pass an instantiated class e.g.

```
$contactController = new ContactController();
call_user_func([$contactController, 'handleContact'])
```

P.S. Setting the handleContact to static would be the easy way out.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately I posted it wrong. I call the function the same as you described. Have adjusted my question to reflect this.

Comment: I just updated my response. Try that out, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine with this solution

Answer (score 3):

As `handleContact` is not a static method, you should instantiate your `ContactController` first and then call the function on the created instance.

You don't even need to use the ugly `call_user_func()` in modern PHP, as you can invoke the callback directly by `()`.

```
  $controller = new ContactController();
  [$controller, 'handleContact']();
```

If however your `handleContact` method doesn't directly operate on `ContactController` instance (i.e. doesn't use `$this` variable), you can convert your method to static by using the `static` keyword in method definition and your original code should work.